# Adobe Media Encoder Flicker Issue

Tags: after-effects

When rendering my video in Adobe Media Encoder using either h.264 and mpeg-2 I get random flickering appearing.

I have rendered directly out of After Effects using a lossless codec. The video is fine, however the file size is obviously way too large.

The source DNG raw files are fine - they have no flicker whatsoever.

Does anyone have any advice for me so I can deliver a flicker free video to the client without a massive file size?

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: Can you post a sample of what kind of flicker you are getting?  This sounds like a very odd issue.  Also, what lossless format are you exporting from and what are the export settings you are using for the h.264 and mpeg-2 outputs?

Comment: Have you tried to export lossless and then to use ffmpeg / mpegstreamclip to reencode? Does the same issue appear then?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a keying effect? Does your flicker look anything like the original images posted here?
https://forums.adobe.com/message/5112063

If so, this issue has been around for a while, and we never seemed to get an accurate response from Adobe. However, there are some workarounds spelled out in that post.